# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 when call SP

Tags: php, sql, laravel, stored-procedures, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and am calling a Stored procedure from a database on the server. Locally it works fine, but on the server, using the same DB, it gives error. The call is as follows (I just want to make select):

```
$result = DB::select('CALL sp_special_prices("'.$codClient.'", "'.$codProduct.'", "'.$quantity.'", "'.$grup.'", "'.$FirmCode.'")');
```

When running a product listing on the server, it works except for two articles, giving the following error:

```
Caught exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 (SQL: CALL sp_special_prices("C000000", "445706049", "1", "146", "75");)
```

I already checked the php versions, and am using 5.6 on both sites. Could it be some special configuration? Is that the DB is the same, the place to call the SP, is that it is different.

Comment: Please post how you use this proc on sql and its output

Comment: @Paras, CALL sp_special_prices("C000000", "445706049", "1", "146", "75") for example

Comment: Does this procedure return anything?

Comment: @Paras, I think it is related to the product code, because it does not return anything to this product, but locally it returns an empty array, and no server gives error.

Comment: check out my answer and let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: @Paras, Returns an array, but in these two exceptions it gives an error, it should not return anything

Answer (score 5):

If the procedure doesn't return anything, you need to use `DB::statement` instead of `DB::select`. If it does return something, you need to use `DB::select`

If the procedure has variable behaviour (may or may not return data depending on input), I suggest you change the procedure to return some data for all input combinations

Comment: Yes, my procedure have variable behavior (may or may not return data depending on input). When you do not return data, should not you return an empty array? Or zero? In my desktop return empty array.